# How to fix this ugly crease on this corner?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces, topology

I am modeling a Z GT500 and I have this ugly crease on this corner despite already trying Looptools flattening/Gstretch:

[image]

Despite the topology isn't that bad:
[image]

I even tried manually moving the middle vertice in the corner but I can't get rid of it, even if it seems to be so simple :/

I include a .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YhHdTOQUBBaDRoVLCQ62NDztvRVjTpm/view?usp=sharing

The rest of the topology looks horrible but that's not the issue as of now.

What method would you use to fix this corner?
Thanks in advance for your help!